# access method from "main" module in ruby when a class has the same method

Tags: ruby

I have this ruby code:

```
def print2(string)
    puts "#{string} #{string}"
end

class String
    def print2
        print2 self
    end
end

print2 "abc"
"abc".print2
```

If I run it, I get this error when calling "abc".print2:

in `print2': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)

I understand why I get the error, but is there any way to be able to call the "top-level" print2 method from inside the print2 method in the String class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a method in the toplevel scope, it gets defined as a private instance method on `Object`. So, this will work:

```
def print2(string)
    puts "#{string} #{string}"
end

class String
    def print2
        super self
    end
end

"abc".print2
```

Because `String` is a subclass of `Object`, `super` refers to the first definition of `print2`.

However, this is probably bad practice. If you are using this in a serious project you should probably put `print2` in a separate module.

Comment: Very nicely explained, in few words. There is a fine point that deserves mention. It can be illustrated by the following example:  `def <(other); puts "hi"; end` then `class String; def <(other); super; end; end`. We find
`"abc" < "def" #=> true`, not `"hi"`, because `Comparable` precedes `Object` in `String.ancestors #=> [Comparable, Object,...]`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ruby does not support overload.

You can try this, you will find it doesn't work.

```
class String
    def print2
        #print2 self
    end

    def print2(string)
       print2
    end
end

"abc".print2
"abc".print2("def")
```

2. ruby methods are found via a depth-first right-to-left search of the receiver’s metaclass’s ancestry.

If `print2` exits in `String` class, ruby won't look for `print2` in `Object` class.

```
irb(main):015:0> String.instance_methods.grep(/print/)
=> [:print2]  #it already exists.
```